# How to get latitude and longitude of my current location in android ? (Not with GPS but with internet service)

Tags: android

I want to get my exact latitude and longitude in android. I don't have GPS in my android device. So, I need to get my location with the help of internet.

&

If getting latitude and longitude fails, show a toast "Failed to get location"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try Network provider

```
    LocationManager lManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

         boolean netEnabled = lManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                if (netEnabled) {
                    lManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
                    location = lManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
  if (location != null) 
                {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();

                        }
                }
```

Comment: Hello +Dilavar , is it necessary to install Google Play Services to use this. Please answer.

Comment: it is not use Google play services.

Answer (score 1):

**Old Ans**
Try using this code. it will give you location from network not fro GPS

```
Location location =myManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
latPoint=location.getLatitude();
lngPoint=location.getLongitude();
```

**Updated ANS**

```
private Location getLastBestLocation() {
Location locationGPS = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
Location locationNet = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

long GPSLocationTime = 0;
if (null != locationGPS) { GPSLocationTime = locationGPS.getTime(); }

long NetLocationTime = 0;

if (null != locationNet) {
    NetLocationTime = locationNet.getTime();
}

if ( 0 < GPSLocationTime - NetLocationTime ) {
    return locationGPS;
}
else {
    return locationNet;
}
}
```

Comment: Hello Umair Khalid. Thanks for your answer. What can I do to configure :

If GPS is available then get location from GPS else use network. Thanks Again.

Comment: getLastKnownLocation() stores the best last location. and if you do not change your location to next point then it will give you the last known location it stores. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this instead of `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER`, use `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER`

```
LocationManager lManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("Network", "Network");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                                System.out.println("latitude network" + latitude+"longi "+location.getLongitude());
                                if (latitude == 0.0) {
                                    showSettingsAlertData();
                                }
                            }
```